# PHP MySQL get amount of rows + display

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have this function (below) and it is supposed to get the amount of users in a table that I have. I know there's 5 users and they all have an ID. However whenever I use the function to display it on a webpage it does not return a result.

This is the function

```
function user_count(){
    mysql_connect("IP", "USER", "PASS");
    mysql_select_db("db");
    return mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id>=0");
}
```

And this is the php for the website

```
<strong><span data-toggle="counter" data-to="
<?php 
$users = user_count();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)){
    echo $row['count']; 
}
?>"></span></strong>
```

Comment: What is "count" in your query? If you want to get the count, you should do "select count(*)  as 'count' from users where id >= 0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) instead.

```
    function user_count(){
        mysql_connect("IP", "USER", "PASS");
        mysql_select_db("db");
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id>=0");
        return mysql_num_rows($result)
    }
```

And then just echo the value, `echo user_count()`.

Also, I would recommend using `mysqli_*` functions, as `mysql_*` is deprecated.